# как в блоке div открыть страницу

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Помогите как в div блоке открыть страницу , фреим устаревшее решения.
Этот код не работает

```
index.html

<script src="assets/player/js/onload.js"></script>
                    <div id="loadplayer">
                Здесь будет плеер с плей листом загружаемый из локальной страницы.
            плеер называетюся RESPONSIVE HTML5 AUDIO PLAYER PRO
                </div>

onload.js    

    function loadPage(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("#loadplayer").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("http://index.html",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: Что будет вставляться, какой код/плеер/плагин?

Comment: Плеер написан на html /css /jquery / ajax, я его разместил бы на сайте но он очень большой, подумал может открыть див и чтоб загружался плеер

Comment: Файл с плеером .html/.php/.js?

Comment: Файл без плеера, плеер написанный кодом

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702704/alternative-to-iframes-with-html5

Comment: это ссылка не помогла , и там фреим предлагают

Comment: @DadoDavudof там чего только не предлагают и <embed> и <object> и объясняют почему иногда надо iframe

Comment: Stranger in the Q   Спасибо за помощь , не обратил внимание,
все получилось с помощью object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Object

```
<object data="https://URL" width="100" height="100" type="text/html">
</object>
```

2) Embed

```
<embed src="https://URL" width=100 height=100 onerror="alert('Неверный URL');" />
```

Comment: Прогоняли через [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/)?